# inline external SVG file from preloaded content

Tags: svg

In my web app I "inline" external SVG file using:

```
function inlineSVG(){
var SVGFile="image/myFile.svg"
loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest();
svgDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
svgDiv.id= "svgInlineDiv";  
svgDiv.style.cssText = 'width:0px;height:0px;'; 
document.body.appendChild(svgDiv);
    if (loadXML != null ){
        loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
        loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
        loadXML.send();
        }
}
function handler(){
            if(loadXML.readyState == 4 && loadXML.status == 200){
            svgDiv.innerHTML=loadXML.responseText
            }
}
```

Is it possible to preload this file and assign "var SVGFile" value retrieved from

```
<link href="image/myFile.svg" rel="preload" >
```

specified in the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `<link rel="preload" >` is only the reordering of *when* a resource is loaded. If you only have the XHR request, it goes out at the time the script is executed. If you define a preload link, the request might be executed earlier. But you still *need* that `loadXML.send();` in your script, it is only that at execution time the resource may already be cached.

Note that preloading [does not delay](https://w3c.github.io/preload/#processing) the document `load` event, so there is no guarantee the resource is already in the cache, only a better chance.

If that is what you want to achieve, set the `as` attribute to signal the destination where the resource will be used:

```
<link id="uniqueid" href="image/myFile.svg" rel="preload" as="fetch" >
```

And if the resource comes from another domain, you might need a `crossorigin` attribute.

To retrieve the file address from the link, you can access it with

```
var SVGFile = document.querySelector('#uniqueid').href;
```

Comment: How I can assign image/myFile.svg path value to variable "var SVGFile"?

Comment: give the link element a unique id to reference it in code. See edit.